# If I have text in a cell within a table, how can I add text to the same cell just aligned to the far right of the cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, cell

If I have text in a cell within a table (that is automatically aligned to the left, which is fine), how can I also add text to the same cell just aligned to the far right of that cell?

For example, the HTML code below, I need to add an asterisk to the very far right of the cell that currently reads **"`<td>Ctrl ⌘ N</td>`"**. How can I do this?

```
<table class="shortcutTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="narrow" lang="en">Shortcut</th>
      <th lang="en">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ctrl ⌘ N</td>
      <td lang="en">Quick Note</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS float property will do what you want. If you have a CSS file already linked in your page, you can make a class for it, but if you just want to put it right in with the HTML, try:

```
<td>Ctrl ⌘ N<span style="float: right">&ast;</span></td>
```